# Get stuck,pull out

Tags: word-usage, american-english

> **My blanket keeps getting stuck under me** and I have to tug at it again and again to **pull it out from under me.**

What ia a natural way to say amd describe the two bold lines? I know that my sentences don't sound natural.  How will you describe it?

Comment: Why don't you think they sound natural?